# how to get rid of FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, camera

I want to make a android video camera app. I want to add some filter in real time in this app. I used OpenGL ES in this app. But it didn't work. I am new in android and openGL also.So, I couldn't figure out it. For better understanding I am giving error log,manefest file,Main Activity and SurfaceView class.
The **ERROR** message be like:

```
    2019-03-20 19:16:03.470 32069-32199/com.example.msi.mcameragl 
    E/MediaPlayerNative: prepareAsync called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
2019-03-20 19:16:03.478 32069-32199/com.example.msi.mcameragl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 205070
    Process: com.example.msi.mcameragl, PID: 32069
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1460)
        at com.example.msi.mcameragl.VideoSurfaceView$VideoRender.onSurfaceCreated(VideoSurfaceView.java:281)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1539)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.msi.mcameragl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.msi.mcameragl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "SamplePlayerActivity";

    protected Resources mResources;

    private VideoSurfaceView mVideoView = null;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mResources = getResources();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            // Load video file from SD Card
            // File dir = Environment
            // .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            // File file = new File(dir,
            // "sample.mp4");
            // mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Load video file from Assets directory
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.mp4");
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        // Initialize VideoSurfaceView using code
        // mVideoView = new VideoSurfaceView(this);
        // setContentView(mVideoView);
        // or
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideoView = (VideoSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mVideoSurfaceView);
        mVideoView.init(mMediaPlayer,
                new DuotoneEffect(Color.parseColor("#3498DB"), Color.YELLOW));
//      If you want to change effect then just call mVideoView.init() again
//      and then call mVideoView.onResume()
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVideoView.onResume();
    }
}
```

**SurfaceView Class**

```
package com.example.msi.mcameragl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * This GLSurfaceView can be used to display video that is being played by media
 * player and at the same time different effect can be applied on the video.
 * This view uses shader for applying different effects.
 *
 * 
 */

public class VideoSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoSurfaceView";
    private VideoRender mRenderer;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private static VideoSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private Context mContext;
    private static ShaderInterface effect;

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new VideoRender(mContext);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mSurfaceView = this;
    }

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new VideoRender(mContext);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mSurfaceView = this;
    }

    /**
     * initializes media player and the effect that is going to be applied on
     * video. The video is played automatically so you dont need to call play.
     *
     * @param mediaPlayer  instance of {@link MediaPlayer}
     * @param shaderEffect any effect that implements {@link ShaderInterface}
     */
    public void init(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, ShaderInterface shaderEffect) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Set MediaPlayer before continuing",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            mMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
        if (shaderEffect == null)
            effect = new NoEffect();
        else
            effect = shaderEffect;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Call init() before Continuing");
            return;
        }
        queueEvent(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
            }
        });

        /*AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your function calling network thread
                mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
            }
        });*/

        super.onResume();
    }

    private static class VideoRender implements Renderer,
            SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
        private static String TAG = "VideoRender";

        private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
        private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
                // X, Y, Z, U, V
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,};

        private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

        private final String mVertexShader = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n"
                + "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n"
                + "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
                + "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n"
                + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
                + "void main() {\n"
                + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n"
                + "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n"
                + "}\n";
        private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
        private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

        private int mProgram;
        private int mTextureID[] = new int[2];
        private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
        private int muSTMatrixHandle;
        private int maPositionHandle;
        private int maTextureHandle;

        private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
        private boolean updateSurface = false;

        private static int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        public VideoRender(Context context) {
            mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer
                    .allocateDirect(
                            mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
        }

        public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player) {
            mMediaPlayer = player;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (updateSurface) {
                    mSurface.updateTexImage();
                    mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                    updateSurface = false;
                }
            }
            mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader,
                    effect.getShader(mSurfaceView));
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT
                    | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID[0]);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES,
                    mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES,
                    mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix,
                    0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            GLES20.glFinish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {

            mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader,
                    effect.getShader(mSurfaceView));
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                return;
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES20
                    .glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,
                    "aTextureCoord");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
            }

            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,
                    "uMVPMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
            }

            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,
                    "uSTMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
            }

            // int[] textures = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextureID, 0);
            // GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID[0]);

            // mTextureID = textures[0];
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID[0]);
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

            // GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            // GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            // GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            // GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            /*
             * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID, and pass
             * it to the MediaPlayer
             */
            mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID[0]);
            mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

            Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            surface.release();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "media player prepare failed");
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                updateSurface = false;
            }

            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        @Override
        synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            updateSurface = true;
        }

        private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
            if (shader != 0) {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
                int[] compiled = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,
                        compiled, 0);
                if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                    shader = 0;
                }
            }
            return shader;
        }

        private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                    fragmentSource);
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
            if (program != 0) {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS,
                        linkStatus, 0);
                if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                    program = 0;
                }
            }
            return program;
        }

        private void checkGlError(String op) {
            int error;
            while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
                throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
            }
        }

    } // End of class VideoRender.

} // End of class VideoSurfaceView.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        **surface.release();**
```

You should not release the surface.